# Помогите правильно составить POJO для ответа Retrofit XML

Tags: java, android, retrofit

Пишу приложение. С сервера приходит ответ в XML:

```
<words>
    <word begin="930" end="1410">корабли</word>
    <word begin="1410" end="2100">лавировали</word>
    <word begin="2100" end="2730">лавировали</word>
    <word begin="2730" end="2970">да</word>
    <word begin="2970" end="3690">невылавировали</word>
</words>
```

Получаю его с помощью Retrofit. Преобразую с помощью SimpleXmlConverterFactory по этой [статье](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-how-to-integrate-xml-converter). Не получается десериализовать его. Пользуюсь вот этим [источником](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php). Не могу найти структуру для класса. Вот этот вариант не подходит:

```
@Root(name = "words")
public class Words {
    @ElementArray
    public String[] word;

}
```

Вот этот тоже не подходит

```
@Root(name = "words")
public class Words {
    @ElementList
    public List<String> word;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 @Root(name = "words")
    public class Words {
    @ElementList
    private List<Word> words;
    // getter/setter
 }

 @Root(name = "word")
    public class Word {
        @Element
        private int begin;

        @Element
        private int end;

        @Element
        private String say;
        // getters/setters
    }
```

Я так понимаю,что-то вроде этого должно быть

Answer (score 0):

Правильный ответ вот этот, если кому интересно
    @Root(name = "words")
    public static class Words {

```
    @ElementList(inline = true)
    public List<Word> word;

}

@Root(name = "word")
public static class Word {

    @Attribute(name = "begin")
    private String begin;

    @Attribute(name = "end")
    private String end;

    @Text
    String value;
}
```

Помогло [это](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php)